# TCP non-blocking socket.connect() and socket.recv() Error questions. (Python or C)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, epoll

I am doing some stress test to a simple HTTP redirect server in Python scripts. The script is set up with epoll (edge trigger mode) with non-blocking sockets. But I observed something that I don't quite understand,

1) epoll can get both ECONNREFUSED and ETIMEOUT errno while the connect() is in process. Don't they both indicates the remote server can't accept the connection? How are they different, how does a client tell the difference?

2) sometimes when EPOLLIN is notified by epoll, socket.recv() returns empty string without any exception thrown (or errno in C), I can keep reading the socket without getting any exception or error, it just always returns empty string. Why is that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ECONNREFUSED` signals that the connection was refused by the server, while `ETIMEOUT` signals that the attempt to connect has timed out, i.e. that no indication (positive or negative) about the connection attempt was received from the peer.
2. `socket.recv()` returning an empty string without error is simply the EOF condition, corresponding to an empty read in C. This happens when the other side closes the connection, or shuts it down for writing. It is normal that `EPOLLIN` is notified when EOF occurs, because you want to know about the EOF (and because you can safely `recv` from the socket without it hanging).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the part I don't understand is that how does the server signal the client that it's refused? Now I think about it, ECONNREFUSED does not indicates that the server accept() queue is full, instead it's basically saying the server port is not open. Is that true? But ETIMEOUT indicates the server is overloaded (ignoring  the underlying unreachability here). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As for EOF, if the peer closed the socket, shouldn't EPOLLHUP also be notified? I tested that, but that flag it's not set.

Comment: @wei On the TCP level, the connection refused signal is accomplished by responding with RST. On the OS level, it is accomplished by not starting the service, or by the listen backlog being full. `ETIMEDOUT` happens when the server is simply not responding at all, typically because it's swamped with requests.

Comment: @wei `EPOLLHUP` occurs when the connection is disconnected and therefore no longer valid for either reading or writing. On the other hand, a connection on which EOF has been received can still be valid for writes and out-of-band data. (These half-duplex connections are obtained in the BSD networking API by calling [`shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) on the socket.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Based on my test, I can see for the FDs that give  0 length 0, I can also see EPIPE error on these FDs in the next epoll.wait(). Is this somehow related? Thanks,

Comment: @wei It could be that epoll is reporting that writing to the socket closed on the other side would result in `EPIPE`.